# NodeJS mySQL Insert Blob

Tags: mysql, node.js, blob

I need a little help
with NodeJS and MySQL blob insertion.

Here's the code snippet i'm using

```
fs.open(temp_path, 'r', function (status, fd) {
    if (status) {
        console.log(status.message);
        return;
    }
    var buffer = new Buffer(getFilesizeInBytes(temp_path));
    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, 100, 0, function (err, num) {
    var query ="INSERT INTO `files` (`file_type`, `file_size`, `file`) VALUES ('img', " + getFilesizeInBytes(temp_path) + ",'" + buffer + "' );";
    mySQLconnection.query(query, function (er, da) {
   if (er)throw er;
   });
  });
});
```

Query inserts the file in the table and I get the correct file size, but when I try
to retrieve the file and open it ( for example a PDF file ) I get a message saying that
the file is corrupted.

I must be doing something wrong with the buffer reading from the file.

Comment: You can't just concatenate a buffer into a query.  In fact, you should never concatenate anything into a query.  How you insert a Blob depends entirely on what MySQL library you're using.  Can you tell us?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
var query ="INSERT INTO `files` (`file_type`, `file_size`, `file`) VALUES ('img', " + getFilesizeInBytes(temp_path) + ",'" + buffer + "' );";
mySQLconnection.query(query, function (er, da) {
```

with:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO `files` SET ?",
    values = {
      file_type: 'img',
      file_size: buffer.length,
      file: buffer
    };
mySQLconnection.query(query, values, function (er, da) {
```

You may also want to change `file: buffer` to `file: buffer.slice(0, 100)` since you are only reading the first 100 bytes of the file. If `buffer.length > 100` then you may end up with a bunch of extra garbage bytes after the first 100 bytes in `buffer`.

Comment: I am curious. I have a similar problem. But I have not just a file in my query. But also normal numbers and text.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you mscdex for the snippet.

The problem was as you pointed out that i was reading only first 100 bytes of data.
BTW thank you for the snippet and here's the whole solution.
Hope it can help someone :-)

```
fs.open(temp_path, 'r', function (status, fd) {
    if (status) {
        console.log(status.message);
        return;
    }
    var fileSize = getFilesizeInBytes(temp_path);
    var buffer = new Buffer(fileSize);
    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, fileSize, 0, function (err, num) {

        var query = "INSERT INTO files SET ?",
            values = {
                file_type: 'img',
                file_size: buffer.length,
                file: buffer
            };
        mySQLconnection.query(query, values, function (er, da) {
            if(er)throw er;
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the small files, you can try below code:

```
var fileInsertSQL = "insert ignore into File(id, content, creationTime) values(?,?,?)";
db.query(fileInsertSQL, ["id1", fs.readFileSync(filepath), new Date().getTime()], function (err, dbRes) {
    if(err){
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        //Do something
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**try using multer buffer:**

```
let query = "UPDATE yourtable SET image=? WHERE id = '1'"
let obj = req.file.buffer;
conn.query(query, obj, function (err, rows, fields) {})
```