# Insert BLOB data in mariaDB using Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mariadb, blob

I want to insert blob data in mariaDB using node js,I am using HeidiSQL to interact with mariaDB.
'users' table have two attributes 'user_email' and 'profile_photo'.

**Similar Question**

I found the following similar question but its not working in my case

[NodeJS mySQL Insert Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951251/nodejs-mysql-insert-blob)

**Here is my code:**

```
const inputfile = "C:\\Users\\Hammad Ali\\Desktop\\bloob\\routes\\CNN.jpg";
var email = "xyz@gmail.com",
   photo = readImageFile(inputfile); 


   var query = "INSERT INTO `users` SET ?",
   values = {
     user_email: email,
     profile_photo: photo
   };
   pool.query(query, values,  function(err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("BLOB data inserted!"+res);
});
});

function readImageFile(file) {
  // read binary data from a file:
  const bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
  const buf = new Buffer.from(bitmap);
  return buf;
}
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: If you included more code, and formatted this cleaner, that would help. What is `pool`?

Comment: pool is conncection object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO `users` (user_email, profile_photo) VALUES (?, ?)",

values = [
  email,
  photo,
];

pool.query(query, values, function(err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("BLOB data inserted!"+res);
});
```

The examples in the MariaDB docs all use arrays, so I changed `values` to an array to match up with what I saw [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connector-nodejs-callback-api/#poolbatchsql-values-callback) and [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connector-nodejs-promise-api/#placeholder).

Comment: Thank You its working,I post it below its show some square boxes.

Comment: can you please help me to retrieve this data from database,decode and send response as multipart to http request

Comment: @HammadAli Glad to help! I'd be happy to help out with the DB retrieval and response cycle. See how far you can get, then ask another question when you get stuck and tag me in the comments and I'll have a look if no one else gets there first.

Comment: I need help in the following question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60906248/connect-mysql-database-with-node-javascript-application