# Connect MySQL database with node JavaScript application

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, cpanel

I make a node JavaScript app and deploy it on cPanel using SSH.
App is working fine without database but when I connect the app with database on cPanel (GoDaddy) it takes times and shows the message "Error establishing a database connection".
My connection code

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var pool = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: '<MY_USER_NAME>',
    password: '<MY_PASSWORD>',
    database: '<DB_NAME>'
});

pool.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  else{
  console.log("Connected!");
  }
});



module.exports = pool;
```

route where DB interact,but lost the connection.

```
app.post('/loginn', (req, res) => {
var id = req.body.id
  console.log("user_id= "+id);
  var sql = "select * from users where id  NOT IN ('" + id + "') ";
    pool.query(sql, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
          res.render('allusers', {
            users: rows,
            user_id:id
          })
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the credentials for the DB correct? Can you connect to the DB at all, or just not in your application?

Comment: I check it in the terminal first connection is build but when I request to any route than connection destroy

Comment: So `Connected!` is printed in the terminal, but when you run a request to a route-handler, the connection is lost, is that correct? Can you post the code where the route-handlers interact with the db?

Comment: i update the post you can check it

Comment: Can you post where the pool is brought in and defined, and any code from this module that closes a db connection? I assume the first example is the relevant connection code for the entire app, but where is that code being `required` in your app?

Comment: var pool = require('./db')

Comment: i require it in the top of the when along with other express modules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210544/discussion-between-danielschroederdev-and-hammad-ali).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is going to take the form of a debugging journey, because that's the only way I can see to get to the bottom of your issue.

Let's do a dead-simple representation of your app to make sure that you can send a query to MySQL and receive a response from a route-handler in Express. Setup your app like this:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = // define the PORT for your host

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: '<MY_USER_NAME>',
    password: '<MY_PASSWORD>',
    database: '<DB_NAME>'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  console.log("Connected!");
});

app.get('/db-test', (req, res, next) => {

  var id = // fill in a user_id that you know exists
  var sql = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN ('${id}') `;

  console.log(sql); // confirm you are sending the sql request you believe you should be sending

  connection.query(sql, function (err, results, fields) {
      if (err) console.error(err);
      console.log(`results: ${results}\nfields: ${fields}`);
  });

});

app.listen(PORT);
```

And then hit the route `/db-test` from your app, and see what happens. If this works, then we will have at least proved that you *CAN* make requests between Express and MySQL. Right now, I'm not sure you can, so I'm not sure what to debug.

Comment: So, the `Connected!` string still prints,  but the request fails?